# qt mouse jumpy when keep mouse centered

Tags: qt, qtopengl

i'm trying to make a fps camera while using QOpenGLWidget, gamer will have a CrossCursor in the center of the screen like most games do.

But when i use

```
QCursor::setPos(geometry().center());
```

the cursor is jumpy, and bounces all over; it really annoys me.
Here is my code:

```
void Widget::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    float xoffset = event->position().x() - rect().center().x();
    float yoffset = rect().center().y() - event->position().y();
    if(firstMouse){
        xoffset = event->position().x();
        yoffset = event->position().y();
        firstMouse = false;
    }
    camera->processMouseMovement(xoffset,yoffset);//camera process
    QCursor::setPos(geometry().center());// keep cenetered
    QOpenGLWidget::mouseMoveEvent(event);
}
```

I don't really know if this `mouseMoveEvent` in `QOpenGLWidget` is same as in the `QWidget`, or maybe there is a better way to implement this function.

Comment: If all you need is a cross in the center of window, then do not use mouse cursor for this. Just paint the cross yourself. And hide the mouse cursor. Very simple.

Comment: thx, it do solve my problems

Answer (score 0):

Could use :

```
    QPoint glob = mapToGlobal(QPoint(width()/2,height()/2));
    QCursor::setPos(glob);
```

2023 04 20 result：
I used the Qt Creator example 'OpenglWindow', which uses QWindow, and modified it to use QWidget instead.

If you want to keep the mouse cursor visible and centered in the window, you can use the setCursor() method of the QWidget class to set the mouse cursor to Qt::BlankCursor to hide it, and then draw a crosshair or other marker in the center of the window to replace the mouse cursor.

```
void OpenGLWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
QPainter painter(this);
painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing, true);
painter.setPen(QPen(Qt::white, 2));

QRect rect = geometry();
QPoint center = rect.center();

int size = 10;
painter.drawLine(center.x() - size, center.y(), center.x() + size, center.y());
painter.drawLine(center.x(), center.y() - size, center.x(), center.y() + size);
}

void OpenGLWindow::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
QRect rect = geometry();
float xoffset = event->pos().x() - rect.center().x();
float yoffset = rect.center().y() - event->pos().y();
if(firstMouse){
    xoffset = event->pos().x();
    yoffset = event->pos().y();
    firstMouse = false;
}
camera->processMouseMovement(xoffset,yoffset);//camera process
QPoint center = rect.center();
QCursor::setPos(mapToGlobal(center)); 
setCursor(Qt::BlankCursor); 
QWindow::mouseMoveEvent(event);
}
```

Also, mapToGlobal may not be needed.

Comment: thx bro,but it didn't solve, still jumpy

Comment: The value of this QPoint is always the same

Comment: still not work, the cursor will still move first and then be moved to the center, which causes bouncing

Comment: Is it right to just simply replace my setPos with yours in mouseMoveEvent?

Comment: I'll have to try it out with qtcreator sometime later, there's still some work to take care of right now